# Seeing where ARC is inserting retain and releases

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is there a compiler option (or some other way) to see where ARC is inserting retain and releases?  This is mostly out of curiosity.  I can see them in the disassembly code, but that's hard to wade through sometimes.

Comment: +1 very interesting question. On the other hand, I can't see how this would help you ever, but I'm sure you've got some situation in mind...?

Comment: It can be helpful if you have to do a lot of __bridge type casts to c code.  Things can get a little confusing, but as I stated, I'm mostly curious.  I like to know how things work not just how to make them work.

Comment: Roger, I don't understand your goal. If you want to control retains etc. then just compile as non-ARC (-fno-objc-arc). ARC is going to add retains just as you would, but perhaps use an earlier -release than you might. This will be the same for both pre-ARC and ARC OSes. Andrew

Comment: As I stated in my question, it's mostly curiosity.  I'd like to understand how the compiler deals with ARC.  It fascinates me.  Knowing stuff like this helps me understand how things work.  I'm the kind of person who buys a cool gadget and immediately takes it apart to see how it works.  Same with ARC.  :-)

Comment: @Yar: what if you want it to work like ARC, but want it to work on iOS 3.x? Then you can't use ARC (which only supports 4.x+), but if it could show you where to insert retains and releases, then you could do it yourself and it would work on iOS 3.x

Answer (score 5):

No. If the compiler were to provide this, you'd get absolutely overwhelmed by the number of retains/releases, since most of them are taken out during the optimization stage. But the compiler can't even do that, because ARC isn't a pre-processing stage. It's part of the compilation. So you're not going to be able to get anything besides looking at the assembly.

Comment: Code that is compiled to work with iOS 4.x, which doesn't really support ARC. That code actually gets inserted into the code before compilation, right?

Comment: @Yar: You're not making any sense. You get the *exact same code* when compiling for 4.x. The only difference is the runtime functions that ARC uses behind the scenes are provided via a library (called libarclite) that Clang links into your binary rather than being provided by the system.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it does not.** I agree though, it would be a pretty neat addition (although it wouldn't serve many functions)!  And like you said, you can look in the disassembly code if you are really curious.