# What's going on with __weak qualified variables under the hood?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Usually `weak` references are used to avoid retain cycles in the application object graph. I understand that part. Now I would like to go a step further and understand how they work under the hood.

Searching a bit, I've read that when I'm using the `__weak` qualifier, the variable associated with that qualifier is registered in an autorelease pool, but what does this mean? Why is the object registered in the pool? What type of pool is used? Is it the main pool or some other specially created one?

When I use this code:

```
id _weak myWeakObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

the compiler gives me a warning that I can fix with:

```
id _strong myStrongObj =  [[NSObject alloc] init];
id _weak myWeakObj = myStrongObj;
```

So, based on the previous question, what happens to the object referenced by `myStrongObj`? If possible, I'd like to know what the compiler's code looks like?

Comment: The actual intermediate (post-ARC) step isn't really available as source. You'd have to look at the assembler to see the retains and releases that are inserted. This is quite a nice question, though!

Comment: Where have you read about autorelease pool and __weak? That's not the case. It's all handled by the Objective-C runtime basically. I shall try to formulate a concise answer shortly...

Comment: @JacquesCousteau Thank you for upvoting and fixing the title. How can see retains and release in assembler? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429857/could-we-see-what-the-arc-correct-to-our-code-in-the-compile-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is your friend:

- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

And also the source for the Objective-C runtime:

- http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/

In particular, take a look at:

- http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-arr.mm
- http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-weak.mm

If you look at `objc_initWeak` and `objc_destroyWeak` as per the 1st link talks about then you'll see how it works "under the hood". The guts is in `weak_register_no_lock` for registering a weak reference and in `weak_unregister_no_lock` for unregistering a weak reference.

I'll leave it up to you to go through and see all the intricacies around how it *actually* works :-).

Comment: So, when I'm using `_weak` no autorelease pool is involved, is it true? Or maybe is there the chance that the compiler adds some magical instruction that creates it? With **That's not the case** are you referring to my code snippet?

Comment: Autorelease pools have no bearing on `__weak`. There may still be an autorelease pool in play, yes. Infact when you load a weak reference (see `objc_loadWeak`) it retains and autoreleases the object for instance. But you don't need to worry about the autorelease pool here - it has no bearing on how a `__weak` variable works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Last question. In `objc_loadWeak`, there is written that *if object is registered as a __weak object, and the last value stored into object has not yet been deallocated or begun deallocation, retains that value and returns it.* Could you explain what does it mean **if object is registered as a __weak object, and the last value stored into object has not yet been deallocated or begun deallocation, retains that value and returns it.**? Thank you again.

Comment: It means that it'll retain the object and return that object if and only if the object has not been deallocated or is in the process of being deallocated. i.e. it'll return you a valid object always, or nil.

Comment: @flexaddicted, but why compiler retains that object and returns it if we explicitly used __weak qualifier?